# jquery ajax call fails when data size exceeds 1119 bytes

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

A button click triggers this code:

```
  $("#testButton").click(function() {        
    var str = $("#ptext").html();
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "/pages/testfn",
      data: { thetext: str }
    })
    .done(function(msg) {
      alert( "success " + msg );
    });       
  });
```

The php that handles this is this:

```
public function testfn() {
  $s = $_POST['thetext'];
  echo strlen($s);
}
```

This works perfectly if the amount of text I have in the #ptext div is less than 1120 bytes. More than that and it silently fails. How can I pass more than 1120 bytes to the testfn function?

Comment: what is the content of `#ptext`? And, as a test, if you replace the content of `#ptext` with some random text (e.g.: 1200 'a' characters), does it still fail or does it work? 1119 bytes seems like a really random number, maybe there's a strange character causing trouble

Answer (score 0):

Check your PHP configuration. This is most likely a configuration issue. Try fiddle with the values below in your `php.ini`:

```
post_max_size=32M
upload_max_filesize=32M
memory_limit=32M
```

32M (megabytes) is just an example, you might want to have other values.

Comment: At your suggestion, I checked php.ini. The current values are post_max_size = 8M, upload_max-filesize = 2M, and memory_limit = 128M. The post is failing around a thousand or so bytes, so these megabyte limits don't seem to be involved.

Answer (score 0):

Well, this is embarrassing. I discovered the problem only occurred when I was testing the site through a proxy server. To get at the site from the "outside" I used a Netshade proxy server in Canada. The clue was that the POST worked when I tested it with my cell phone browser. So I used the local IP address and turned off the proxy server and it all works.